# Chebyshev's inequality for Poisson distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Reading an old Richard Karp paper, in which he mentions this argument "Application of Chebyshev's inequality yields the result that, if $X$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$, then $E(X\log_2 X) \leq \lambda \log_2 \lambda + 4/3$", How is Chebyshev's inequality applied here? I could not get around this argument.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\la\lambda$I have been unable to recreate the reasoning behind the inequality
\begin{equation*}
    EX\log_2 X \le \la \log_2 \la + 4/3. \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}

However, first we will see here that there is a simple way to get a bound slightly weaker than that in \eqref{0} -- namely, with $4/3$ in \eqref{0} replaced by
\begin{equation*}
    c_0:=1/\ln2=1.442\ldots \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
which is just a bit greater than $4/3=1.333\ldots$.

Moreover, working a bit harder, we will get an improvement of \eqref{0} --  with a smaller constant in place of $4/3$ there.

Indeed, using the Stein–Chen identity
$$EXf(X)=\la\, Ef(X+1)$$
for $f=\ln$, then Jensen's inequality for the concave function $\ln$, and finally the inequality $\ln(1+u)\le u$ for $u>-1$, we get
\begin{equation}
X\ln X=\la E\ln(X+1)\le\la \ln(\la+1) \\ 
=\la\ln\la+\la \ln(1+1/\la)\le\la\ln\la+1, \tag{20}\label{20}   
\end{equation}
so that
$$EX\log_2 X\le\la\log_2\la+c_0, $$
with $c_0$ as defined in \eqref{10}.

---

Now the mentioned harder work:

Take any real $\la>1$. Write
\begin{equation*}   
\begin{aligned}
    E\ln(X+1)-\ln\la&=E\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}t\,[e^{-\la t}-e^{-(X+1)t}] \\ 
    &=\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}t\,[e^{-\la t}-Ee^{-(X+1)t}] \\ 
    &=\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}t\,e^{-\la t}[1-e^{t(\la r(t)-1)}] \\  
    &\le\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}t\,g_t(\la) \\  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    r(t):=\frac{e^{-t}-1+t}t=\int_0^1ds\,(1-e^{-ts}) \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    g_t(\la):=\max(0,e^{-\la t}[1-e^{t(\la r(t)-1)}]), 
\end{equation*}
so that $r$ is continuously and strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$ from $0$ to $1$.
So, for any real $t>0$
\begin{equation*}
    g_t(\la)\ne0\iff r(t)<1/\la\iff t<t_\la,
\end{equation*}
where $t_\la$ is the only root $t$ of the equation $r(t)=1/\la$. So,
\begin{equation*}   
\begin{aligned}
    E\ln(X+1)-\ln\la\le\int_0^{t_\la}\frac{dt}t\,g_t(\la).    
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Next, for real $t>0$,
\begin{equation*}
    g_t(\la)=e^{-\la t}[1-e^{t(\la r(t)-1)}]
    \le e^{-\la t}[1-e^{-t}]\le e^{-\la t}t. 
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}   
\begin{aligned}
    \la E\ln(X+1)-\la\ln\la\le\la\int_0^{t_\la}dt\,e^{-\la t}
    =1-e^{-\la t_\la}.     
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Further, $r(t)$ is increasing in $t>0$ and hence $t_\la$ is decreasing in $\la>1$. Also, in view of \eqref{30}, $r(t)/t$ is decreasing in $t>0$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \la t_\la=\frac{t_\la}{r(t_\la)}
\end{equation*}
is decreasing in $\la>1$.

So, letting
\begin{equation*}
    \la_0:=4.61028,
\end{equation*}
we see that
\begin{equation*}   
\begin{aligned}
    \la E\ln(X+1)-\la\ln\la\le1-e^{-\la_0 t_{\la_0}}
    =:c_1=0.90505\ldots \quad\text{if}\quad\la\ge\la_0.      
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

On the other hand, $\la \ln(1+1/\la)$ is concave and hence increasing (to $1$) in $\la>0$, so that, in view of \eqref{20},
\begin{equation*}
EX\ln X-\la\ln\la\le\la \ln(1+1/\la)\le\la_0 \ln(1+1/\la_0)=:c_2=0.90505\ldots \quad\text{if}\quad\la\le\la_0.
\end{equation*}
We conclude that for all real $\la>0$
\begin{equation*}
    EX\log_2 X-\la\log_2\la\le\frac{\max(c_1,c_2)}{\ln2}=:c=1.3057\ldots<4/3. \quad\Box
\end{equation*}

Comment: A neat proof! Bravo.

Comment: @OmarR : Thank you for your comment. Can you give a reference to the "old Richard Karp paper"?

Comment: "Probabilistic Analysis of Partitioning Algorithms for the Traveling-Salesman Problem in the Plane" - Richard M. Karp 1977

Comment: Where did the name "Stein–Chen identity" come from? Herbert Robbins introduced this identity in the 1950s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_lemma

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Thank you for your comment. See e.g. [this](https://dornsife.usc.edu/larry-goldstein/wp-content/uploads/sites/221/2023/06/pacs.pdf). Things get re-discovered.

Comment: @OmarR : Thank you for the reference.